# Paths showing up in link_to 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, path, routes, link-to

I am new to rails having just completed rails for zombies (railsforzombies.org) and am trying to build my first app (a blog).

I have scaffolded a basic structure and made changes including changing routes adding partials and other improvements to the view as well as installing the Blueprint css framework.

The problem I'm having is that all of my links (created with link_to) end up looking like this:

```
test post(/post/1)
```

Where the path to the link is printed after the link itself. However, I cannot copy the text with the path to the link.

In case it helps this is what my routes.rb looks like:

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do |map|
  root :to => "Posts#index"
  match '/post/:id' => 'Posts#show', :as => 'show'
  match 'new' => 'Posts#new', :as => 'new_post'
```

Any help?

Edit:

my link_to call is as follows:

```
<em><h2 class = "title"><%=link_to post.title, show_path(post.id) %></h2></em>
```

Edit:

The problem can be seen in [this image](http://img208.imageshack.us/i/screenshot20101229at125.png/).

Also if I change to show_url the url appears in the parenthesis as opposed to the path.

Comment: Could you show us your link_to call (and the surrounding lines)?

Comment: Have you run `rake routes`? To the left of each route is the name, to which you can append `_url` or `_path`.

Comment: Please post the HTML generated for the link as well.

Comment: <em><h2 class = "title"><a href="/posts/1">test post</a></h2></em>

Comment: The HTML is "pure" so that means *something* (javascript?) seems to be appending the extra text within the `<a>` tag! Maybe you have some browser plugin that shows the link's URL next to the link? Or maybe some CSS is appending it (seems very unlikely though).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem solved.

Blueprint CSS was messing up my code. To avoid this, make sure you specify the `:media` option when including the Blueprint CSS files. Your code should look something like this:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/screen', :media => 'screen' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/print', :media => 'print' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/ie'%>
```

Answer (score 0):

These are things that *may* be the problem, so please check:

1. In `match '/post/:id' .....`, `post` should be plural I believe.
2. Not sure, but also try adding a space between `<%=` and `link_to`.
3. Change `show_path(post.id)` to `show_path(post)` in the `link_to`?