# Ruby on Rails link issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this syntax in my code, but it displays differently:

```
<a href="http://railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
```

Result in browser:

```
(Ruby on Rails Tutorial(http://railstutorial.org
```

Can someone tell me whats wrong? I have a Rails 3.1.3 version and a ruby 1.9.2p0 version.

Comment: <h1>Sample App</h1>
   
      <p>
<a href="http://railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
       </p>

Comment: Can you show the surrounding area of the code?

Comment: <h1>Sample App</h1> <p> <a href="railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a> </p> //this is all the code in the page. the page is in the views file

Comment: Put "http://" before "railstutorial.org"

Comment: Let's take a step back: what's in your controller for this method? can you put everything between def and end?

Comment: `class PagesController < ApplicationController
    def home                 
    end
  
    def contact              
    end
    
    def about
   end
      
  end`

Comment: the view belongs to the home method, the method has nothing on it actually.

Comment: ahhh I got it now its because of this  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>   a css problem i guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this same problem, it was solved by correcting my stylesheet linking, and a better understanding the Assets Pipeline. The Blueprint css folder I included as a result of an older rails tutorial was the source of the issue.  I was allowing rails to compile something from these folders into my app/assets/stylesheets/application.css file incorrectly, without defining :media as screen or print.

I solved this issue by writing my own css files, including them in the same folder as app/assets/stylesheets/application.css, adding the .scss extension (style.css.scss) (rails 3.1.3) linking only to the "application" file, and deleting the Blueprint css library folder from my app/assets/stylesheets/ folder entirely, where it shouldn't have been in the first place.

```
   #  For rails 3.0 and up, delete blueprint folder and
   #  put any custom css files you want in the app/assets/stylesheets folder by 
   #  themselves, adding the .scss extension.They should automatically be loaded into 
   #  application.css through  the assets pipeline.
   #  In your stylesheets helper layout file, or application layout file,
   #  (where ever you keep your stylesheet linking), only link to:

   stylesheet_link_tag "application"
```

Alternatively, if you're not using 3.0 or above, and aren't dealing with the Asset pipeline, the issue may be resolved by defining the media type of the stylesheets you are linking to:

```
   stylesheet_link_tag "blueprint/screen", :media => "screen"
```

There is another post referencing this issue:

[Similar Problem...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554915/paths-showing-up-in-link-to)

Answer (score -1):

[Try using the "link_to" method in RoR:](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)

```
link_to(body, url, html_options = {})
```

or

```
link_to("Ruby on Rails Tutorial", "http://railstutorial.org")
```

or

```
link_to "Ruby on Rails Tutorial", "http://railstutorial.org"
```

Comment: Something is wrong before this statement. You're not escaping ruby or closing a statement properly I suspect.